# What is the distribution of a random variable $U$ with $P(U⩾t)=\exp(−∫_0^t r(s)ds)$?

Tags: probability

From Did's comment following [his reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/297159/3616), given a random variable $U$ with $P(U⩾t)=\exp(−∫_0^t r(s)ds)$ for some function $r:[0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ every $t⩾0$.

Is there a name for such a distribution?

If $r$ is constant, then $U$ has an exponential distribution.

If $r$ is piecewise constant, what is the name of the distribution? "Piecewise exponential"?

Thanks!

Comment: Again, pursuing on a previous question without saying so...

Comment: @Did: I added the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if the distribution has a name, but it is the probability of the next arrival in an [inhomogenous Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-homogeneous_Poisson_process) taking time greater than $t$, i.e., $P(X>t)$ where $X$ is the inter-arrival time.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask where you see the interarrival time for an inhomogeneous Poisson process has the distribution?

Comment: @Ethan: For a normal Poisson process, it is $exp(-\lambda t)$. In inhomogeneous process, the $\lambda$ varies with time as $\lambda(t)$.